# Update statement is not working in SQL Server 2014 using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using SQL server 2014. I can access the data and show in the ASP. net application. But I am not able to update the data.

```
using(SqlConnection cn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebTeamServersConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    string[] words1 = fields.Split(',');
    string sql = "UPDATE [Web Team Servers] SET ";
    foreach (string s1 in words1)
    {
        if (ct1 == 1)
        {
            sql = sql + s1 + " = '@Param" + ct1 + "'";
        }
        else
        {
            sql = sql + ", " + s1 + " = '@Param" + ct1 + "'";
        }
        ct1 = ct1 + 1;
    }
    sql = sql + " WHERE Server = '@Server'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,cn1);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Server", strServer);
    string[] words = values.Split(',');

    foreach (string s in words)
    {
        string param = "@param" + ct;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param, s);
        ct = ct + 1;
    }
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    try
    {
        cn1.Open();
        int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        cn1.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe it is something along the lines of `cn1.SaveChanges()`, IIRC

Comment: You have a number of issues with your code here. Let's start with the try-squelch anti-pattern. You have an empty catch which is just awful. How will you ever know if there is an error?? Next issue is using AddWithvalue for every column. This will sometimes gets things wrong. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: You're swallowing the exception (if any occurs) in your catch block.  Don't do that.  Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?  Have you taken the generated SQL and tried running in it SSMS?

Comment: Also, you don't need the close in the finally block.  The `using` command will close the connection for you even if an exception occurs.

Comment: You also have wrapped every one of your parameters in single quotes. When this executes it will be looking for the string literal instead of the parameter value. For example. This " WHERE Server = '@Server'"; should be " WHERE Server = @Server";

Comment: Thank you @SeanLange. It worked. taking out ' worked. This " WHERE Server = '@Server'"; should be " WHERE Server = @Server"

Comment: You should also consider wrapping this connection with a transaction (Good Practice). In case anything ever happens you'll have a sleek way of identifying if it succeeds- proceed with the commit or fails- rollback.

Comment: Can you show me how to?  @FirebladeDan

Comment: @SeanLange Edit below for point allotment

Comment: @FirebladeDan not sure what you mean by "Edit below for point allotment"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transaction example and cleaning some of your code:

**Make sure to put in your changes that fixed the issue

(Some I left in case you were reusing)

(using* clause implements IDisposable which will clean up the connection for you)

```
//rename ct1, ct and fields to something meaningful. This will help you when you have ct1-ct1000 :)
        using(SqlConnection cn1 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WebTeamServersConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {
          string[] words1 = fields.Split(',');

          #region Build UPDATE SqlQuery
          string sql = "UPDATE [Web Team Servers] SET ";


          foreach (string s1 in words1)
          {
            if (ct1 == 1)
            {
                sql = sql + s1 + " = '@Param" + ct1 + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                sql = sql + ", " + s1 + " = '@Param" + ct1 + "'";
            }
            ct1 = ct1 + 1;
          }

          sql = sql + " WHERE Server = @Server";
          #endregion

          //have to open your connection first
          cn1.Open();

          //begins the transaction
          SqlTransaction transaction = cn1.BeginTransaction();

          //hook up your transaction to the command in question
          using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,cn1,transaction))
          {

            try
            {
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Server", strServer);
               string[] words = values.Split(',');

               foreach (string s in words)
               {
                 string param = "@param" + ct;
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param, s);
                 ct = ct + 1;
               }
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

               //will commit automagically
               int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

               //makes it super obvious we agree with the transaction
               transaction.Commit();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              //if shiite hits the fan undo changes to db
              transaction.Rollback();

              Console.WriteLine(ex.Message+","+ex.StackTrace);
            }

          }
        }
```

Comment: This is what I call the try-squelch anti-pattern. You do cleanly catch any errors but you also silently handle them. This means the application and the user has no idea anything went wrong. And it still has the parameter that I pointed out earlier.

Comment: You should've been able to edit my answer no? hmm didn't want to take your glory just wanted to show transaction... Error Handling wasn't the exercise but agreed

Comment: There is no glory to steal here. :) In your example the transaction seems to be overkill to me anyway. There is only 1 statement being executed so there is already an implicit transaction happening.